# Get HTML element value using WKWebKit and Swift 3

Tags: javascript, html, swift, wkwebview

Trying to get an html element name or value using preferred evaluate Javascript swift function using a WKWebView. I keep recieving nil.  I think maybe my function is firing before the page is loaded, thus never finding the element.  Right now just trying to get the element text by class name.  Here is my code below in the ViewController

```
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

        var web: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        web = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        web.uiDelegate = self
        view = web
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.appcoda.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        web.load(myRequest)

        web.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByClassName('excerpt').innerText") {(result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                    print(String(describing:result))
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right. The website won't finish loading by the time you call `evaluateJavascript`. But there are also other errors:

- You should set the `navigationDelegate` instead of `uiDelegate`
- Due to App Transport Security, URL requests to `http` addresses are disallowed. Use `https` if the website supports it or [configure your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35) appropriately.
- You misspelled the function name (missing the the `s` after `getElement`)
- `getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you have to pick what element you want to find the `innerText` of

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    web = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    web.navigationDelegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.appcoda.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    web.load(myRequest)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    web.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('excerpt')[0].innerText") {(result, error) in
        guard error == nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        print(String(describing: result))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this issue.  Unfortunately it did not work.  Punching in this code and commenting mine, the web view wont load.  There is also a guard error which is no big deal to fix.  Could there be something else i'm missing?  @Code Different